# Give multiple tags on a button

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for giving at least one tag in my button.

```
 button1.Tag= "FirstTag";

 MessageBox.Show(button1.Tag.ToString());
```

How can i add at least one more tag in my button.I'm looking for something easy and quick

Comment: Tag is `object` so you can put whatever you'd like there. Specifically `List<object>` or `List<string>`. You could also potentially create a class that holds `Tag1` and `Tag2` properties, and assign it to the button's `Tag`

Comment: @OfirWinegarten, looks like an answer to me.  You should write one.